# Undefined data after storing API response to cache

Tags: javascript, caching, fetch

I am building a simple JS application that fetches data from an API. It's working fine but now that I'm trying to implement the cache API I'm running into some issues.

My fetchData function:

```
function fetchUsers(){
 fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        let resClone = response.clone();
        response.json();
        cache.storeResponse("requestsCache", request, resClone);  // cache data
      })
      .then((data) => { 
        users.push(...data.users);
        this.displayResults(users);
      });
}
```

And the cache functions I'm using:

```
const cache = {
  canUseCache: function () {
    return "caches" in window;
  },

  getCachedResponse: async function (cacheName, request) {
    if (!this.canUseCache) {
      return false;
    }
    const openCache = await caches.open(cacheName);
    const cachedResponse = await openCache.match(request);

    if (!cachedResponse || !cachedResponse.ok) {
      return false;
    }
    let cachedData = await cachedResponse.json();
    return cachedData;
  },

  storeResponse: async function (cacheName, request, response) {
    if (!this.canUseCache) {
      return false;
    }
    const opencache = await caches.open(cacheName);
    opencache.put(request, response);
  },
};
```

After adding the `cache.storeResponse` line now my data is undefined. I haven't used cache before so any help would be much appreaciated.

Comment: in the first `then` section of code where you clone the response you do not return a value as far as I can tell

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius hmm I was under the assumption response.json() would be used as the value for the following `then` statement. I don't have anything to return when storing the clone response to the cache. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: my understanding ( which may well be wide of the mark ) is that within an arrow function if you use curly braces then you must manually set the return whereas without the curly braces the return is implicit.